# Scrapy - Extract Data from mutliple pages

Tags: python-3.x, url, scrapy

```
class HomedepotcrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'homeDepotCrawl'
      allowed_domains = ['homedepot.com']
      start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/b/N-5yc1v/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&experienceName=default&Nao=0']

def parse(self, response):

    #call home depot function
    for item in self.parseHomeDepot(response):
        yield item

    nextPageSelect = '.hd-pagination__link'
    next_page = response.css(nextPageSelect).getall()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

Edit-

The way I got .hd-pagination__link was using a CSS selector extension for google chrome and selected the next page icon (Screenshot attached)

[image: Screenshot of css for next page]

So I've tried a few things and this is the way that made the most sense to me and I think that I'm just grabbing the wrong object for the next page. As of right now my program only grabs the data from the first page and seems like the code block to traverse pages is being ignored.

I found a pattern with the URL where page numbers are denoted within increments of 24 (Maybe due to items numbers?). EX:

Page 1: https://www.homedepot.com/b/N-5yc1v/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&experienceName=default&Nao=0

Page 2: https://www.homedepot.com/b/N-5yc1v/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&experienceName=default&Nao=24

page 3: https://www.homedepot.com/b/N-5yc1v/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&experienceName=default&Nao=48
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

page n: https://www.homedepot.com/b/N-5yc1v/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&experienceName=default&Nao=[(n*24) - 24]

ect.

When I tried testing out code related to page numbers[incrementing the number after Na0 = x], I would just loop through the first page x amount of times. (My output would be the first page (24 items) repeated x amount of times.

I've also looked into crawl spider but couldn't really understand it/implementation.

Any help with my code/clarification on other methods would be appreciated!

Also this is not my whole program, I'm keeping out my parseHomeDepot function because I don't think it is necessary, but if the code is needed, just let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some working code for what you want to do:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urljoin

class HomedepotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'homedepot'
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/b/N-5yc1v/Ntk-ProductInfoMatch/Ntt-zline?NCNI-5&experienceName=default&Nao=0']

    def parse(self, response):

        # Here you do something with your items

        next_page = response.css('a.hd-pagination__link[title=Next]::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            o = urlsplit(response.url)
            base_url = f'{o.scheme}://{o.netloc}'
            next_page_url = urljoin(base_url,next_page)
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

The main things I would point you to in this code are:

1. Check the selector for the next page. It checks the attribute title and only selects the  element that has title "Next". That is to identify the last button in the pagination. I´m not sure if your example is identifying the right button
2. The next page you get is a relative url. What this does is use urljoin to get the base part of the current url (`response.url`) and then appends this relative you are getting to that with urljoin
3. Once you have the url of the next page you just can use response.follow to indicate the spider to add that url with your selected callback to the list of urls to crawl

Also here is the scrapy logs showing it has crawled 31 pages. This is what you should get if you execute it

```
2020-02-21 10:42:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 44799,
 'downloader/request_count': 31,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 31,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1875031,
 'downloader/response_count': 31,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 31,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 13.690273,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 21, 10, 42, 4, 145686),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 32,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 52195328,
 'memusage/startup': 52195328,
 'request_depth_max': 31,
 'response_received_count': 31,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 31,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 31,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 31,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 31,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 21, 10, 41, 50, 455413)}
2020-02-21 10:42:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Can you explain what o.scheme does and how you got it?

Comment: That part of the code "builds" the url of the next page. From the href in the link from the pagination button you have a relative reference i.e. "second half" of the url. The way this goes about it is to get the url of the page you are in from request.url. Then "break it" with urlsplit to get the pieces you need. Specifically you need the scheme, that would be the "http://" in the address and the domain "homedepot.com". You put those two together with the second half from the pagination href - You can check the urlsplir docs for more detail  https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me like you have a couple issues.

First of all, you may be getting the whole html element that contains the link for the next page, whereas what you're looking for is the link only. So I suggest you use the css selector like so:

```
nextPageSelect = '.hd-pagination__link::attr(href)'
```

This will get you the links instead of the whole HTML element. I suggest looking further into css selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Secondly, there seems to be an issue with your code, logically.

```
next_page = response.css(nextPageSelect).getall()
```

this piece of code gets you a list of all the 'next page' links on your current page, but you treat the whole list as one link. I suggest a `for` loop. Something like this:

```
   if next_pages:
    for page in next_pages:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

Now moving on, I think to better make use of Scrapy's parallel and concurrency features, you may want to return a list of 'scrapy.Requests' instead of doing a `yield` for every request you find. So to summarize:

```
nextPageSelect = '.hd-pagination__link::attr(href)'
next_pages = response.css(nextPageSelect).getall()
requests = []
if next_pages:
    for page in next_pages:
        requests.append(scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(page),
            callback=self.parse
        ))
return requests
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out this method tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: So I've tried the method and editing it to my program, I'm still only getting the first page, should I post my whole program

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

Get current page number and using it as reference, get next page's number and then use it in url after multiplying with the counter

```
try:
    nextpage_number = response.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'hd-pagination')]/li/a[contains(@class,'active ')]/ancestor::li[1]/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@title")[0].extract()
    current_url_stip = re.search( r"(.+Nao=)\d+", response.url)
    new_url = "%s=%s" % ( current_url_stip.group(1), nextpage_number * 24 )
    yield scrapy.Request(new_url, meta=response.meta)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank You! I'll try this out tomorrow, with the line new_url = "<your_url>" + ( nextpage_number * 24 ), how would I add the int to a string?

Comment: something like new_url  = "%s%s" % (old_url, nextpage_number * 24)

Comment: So url then replace the page num with %s(act as a string) and + (concat) (next page * 24)?

Comment: So I'm still only getting the first page, would it be more helpful for me to post my whole program?